# Legality of Syrian invasion by US and allies

Tags: united-states, international-law, united-nations, syria, nato

UN Security Council unanimously adopted Resolution 2249, aimed at rallying the world behind the fairly obvious notion that ISIS is an “unprecedented threat to international peace and security.”

“It’s a call to action to member states that have the capacity to do so to take all necessary measures against (ISIS) and other terrorist groups,” British UN Ambassador Matthew Rycroft told reporters.

There are a lot of laws that seek to govern and prevent wars, but the Western nations looking to launch airstrikes in Syria have made things easy for us – they have cited the law that they believe justifies their military intervention: specifically, Article 51 of the UN Charter. It reads, in part:

> Nothing in the present Charter shall impair the inherent right of
>   individual or collective self-defense if an armed attack occurs
>   against a Member of the United Nations, until the Security Council has
>   taken measures necessary to maintain international peace and security.

So doesn’t France, for instance, enjoy the inherent right to bomb ISIS targets in Syria as an act of self-defense – in order to prevent further attacks?

And don’t members of the US-led coalition, who cite the “collective self-defense” of Iraq (the Iraqi government has formally made this request), have the right to prevent further ISIS attacks from Syrian territory into Iraqi areas?

Well, no. Article 51, as conceived in the UN Charter, refers to attacks between territorial states, not with non-state actors like ISIS or Al-Qaeda. Syria, after all, did not attack France or Iraq – or Turkey, Australia, Jordan or Saudi Arabia.

Ostensibly, Syria is ‘unable’ to sufficiently degrade or destroy ISIS because, as we can clearly see, ISIS controls a significant amount of territory within Syria’s borders that its national army has not been able to reclaim.

This made some sense – until September 30 when Russia entered the Syrian military theater and began to launch widespread airstrikes against terrorist targets inside Syria.

As a major global military power, Russia is clearly ‘able’ to thwart ISIS –certainly just as well as most of the Western NATO states participating in airstrikes already. Moreover, as Russia is operating there due to a direct Syrian government appeal for assistance, the Russian military role in Syria is perfectly legal.

This development struck a blow at the US-led coalition’s legal justification for strikes in Syria. Not that the coalition’s actions were ever legal – “unwilling and unable” is merely a theory and has no basis in customary international law.

About this new Russian role, Major Patrick Walsh, associate professor in the International and Operational Law Department at the US Army’s Judge Advocate General’s Legal Center and School in Virginia, says:

> The United States and others who are acting in collective defense of
>   Iraq and Turkey are in a precarious position. The international
>   community is calling on Russia to stop attacking rebel groups and
>   start attacking ISIS. But if Russia does, and if the Assad government
>   commits to preventing ISIS from attacking Syria’s neighbors and
>   delivers on that commitment, then the unwilling or unable theory for
>   intervention in Syria would no longer apply. Nations would be unable
>   to legally intervene inside Syria against ISIS without the Assad
>   government’s consent.

From “the dictator is killing his own people” to the “regime is using chemical weapons” to the need to establish “No Fly Zones” to safeguard “refugees fleeing Assad”…propaganda has been liberally used to build the justification for foreign military intervention.

Article 2 of the UN Charter states, in part:

> All Members shall refrain in their international relations from the
>   threat or use of force against the territorial integrity or political
>   independence of any state, or in any other manner inconsistent with
>   the purposes of the United Nations.

It’s hard to see how Syria’s sovereignty and territorial integrity has not been systematically violated throughout the nearly five years of this conflict, by the very states that make up the US-led coalition. The US, UK, France, Saudi Arabia, Turkey, Qatar, the UAE and other nations have poured weapons, funds, troops and assistance into undermining a UN member state at every turn.

Why than does it always seem the US and NATO allies are always exempt from international laws when it comes to interventions?

Comment: "Why than does it always seem the US and NATO allies are always exempt from international laws when it comes to interventions?"  Every nation is technically exempt from international law as there is no world government which has ultimate sovereignty over the nations; international laws are treaties, and at the end of the day the nations are sovereign and can withdraw or ignore them at will.

Comment: So Assad's use of chemical weapons, Iran and Russia's intervention in Syria to maintain dictatorship and drive a refugee crisis or support Isis is fine, but Western states intervention on behalf of the Syrian people is illegal?     Reading questions like yours you'd think Syria is this united nation that the US is picking on.   Syria was in a civil war, trying to overthrow an unpopular dictator.   Many Syrians wanted the US's intervention.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean by legal. Bashar Assad *is* the leader of the Syrian government, but he's not exactly what you would call democratically elected. He's not even popular, like some non-democratically chosen leaders such as Putin. In fact, a good portion of the country felt so strongly about his leadership that they were willing to wage war against him. Given that he's an Alawite, with his government rather preferential to Alawites, but the country is majority-Sunni, that's perhaps not so surprising.

Comment: So I think Assad could just as easily be seen as an unpopular dictator seeking foreign assistance to maintain minority rule, as the legitimate government of Syria seeking foreign assistance to eject invaders.

Comment: @userLTK -Well, let's not be *so* sunny about the motivations of the US and their allies here. They've got their realpolitik considerations just like the rest. I think eliminating ISIS, which is a domestic terrorism threat, supporting their ally Iraq, and possibly depriving Russia of an ally in the region are higher on their list than trying to help the Syrian people. I'm not saying that no one has that motivations - but it's not high on the list of things driving policy.

Comment: When you say "From 'the dictator is killing his own people' to the 'regime is using chemical weapons'...…propaganda has been liberally used to build the justification for foreign military intervention", are you suggesting that those things aren't true? Setting aside the definitely dubious benefit of military intervention in Syria, the first point is true, and the second point is very likely true. Not that that necessarily justifies international involvement in the war in Syria, of course.

Comment: @Obie2.0  I think there's little doubt that both Russia and Assad have been butchers.   Russia bombs hospitals.  Their airstrikes circle back and bomb rescue missions.   They and Assad are trying to beat down the opposition every way they can.   The US may not be, as you say, "sunny" but it's hard to deny that the opposition to Assad are being beaten down with little to no representation and little hope.   In response to the original question, does that give the US and it's allies a legal right to step in?   I think it does because without the US, they have no power and no rights.

Comment: @UserLTK, What legal right does the US have for invading a sovereign nation that posed no direct threat? Article 51, Chapter VII of the UN Charter, states have the right to mobilize their military forces in self-defense if they are attacked. You do know the US also bombed Kunduz hospital in Afghanistan in 2015? This is just another case of the kettle calling the pot black.

Comment: @Noah Was Nazi Germany a threat to the US during WW2 or was our action preemptive?   Japan bombed us, not Germany.    Due to Russian action, nearly a million Syrians crossed the border into European allies.  Another million or more are in refugee camps in Turkey, Any who can are applying for refugee status in the US.    Assad also blocked a natural gas pipeline that the US supported.   Assad used chemical weapons and starvation against his own people and even worked with ISIS against them.    At what point do you recognize the basis for a moral imperative?   That's what right the US had.

Comment: @Noah and I'm absolutely stunned that you would use the bombing of the hospital in Afganistan as a counter example.  The Russian bombing of hospital is deliberate and repeated often - basically every hospital in Aleppo was bombed into rubble.   The US ADMITTED it made a GRAVE ERROR in their one bombing of that hospital.  It was a tragedy, NOT NATIONAL POLICY.    No matter what you might think of US foreign policy, you should recognize that distinction.   And please don't think I support everything the US does - this question was specifically about why go into Syria.

Comment: @userLTK Yes, IT IS fine. What problem you have with intervention by countries that were officially invited to intervene? That they're not your beloved Western masters?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov  Huge grey area there.   Assad killed more people than anyone else this decade.  He used chemical weapons on his own people.  He made deals with Isis.   That Assad invited Russia to intervene isn't exactly an argument that it's all good.   Now, I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that there's often no good choices, just different levels of bad during a national crisis/civil war.  But certainly Assad inviting Russia's assistance doesn't make it puppies and roses, nor does it make it better than, say, US efforts to defend those who otherwise would get crushed, like the Kurds.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov  I would add that the Russians bombed hospitals.  They would bomb a city, wait for the rescue efforts and bomb the rescue efforts.   When you say "my believed western masters", let me be clear.   I have no master, no do I consider US intervention beloved.  I think the US gets a lot wrong.   But what you are defending as "by invitation" is arguably much worse and I would call it, indefensible.

Comment: @userLTK But the one crushing kurds is not Russia or Asad, but Turkey one of the main US alies in the region.

Comment: Turkey is a funny ally, and the US protects the Kurds from Turkey.   Erdogan encouraged Trump to pull out.   Trump (like a moron) trusted him and pulled out.  Erdogan began killing Kurds and Trump had to send troops back in.    The Kurds are US allies.   Erdogan is more of an independent.   He's not on Russia's side either, and if I have my facts right, Erdogan hates Assad, so he's more of a wildcard.     I don't mean to say that the US is perfect, because I don't think the US is perfect.   But it's easy to find flaws in Assad and Putin during this conflict.   Basically supporting genocide.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Historically, United Nations never had any chances to interfiere the will of United States or any of their allies. Syria is not an isolated case and we need to see two examples about the US behavior in the foreign policy to understand this point of view:

- Cuba's embargo: Since 1992, every year, the United Nations (specifically the General Assembly) [approves a resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_embargo_against_Cuba#Criticism_of_embargo_laws_and_rules) condemning the embargo; however, United States never obey these resolutions. What Obama did is open the negotiation channel but to have (again) a diplomatic relation as we know in the international relations field, there are some steps to be done.
- Iraq's war: In the legal point of view, Iraq's invasion was illegal because the decision was made unilaterally and not the Security Council. In the [words of Kofi Annan](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/middle_east/3661134.stm), General Secretary of the UN in those times:

> Yes, if you wish. I have indicated it was not in conformity with the UN charter from our point of view, from the charter point of view, **it was illegal**.

With these two examples, I want to show that they acted (and they're currently acting) illegally but the main reason they don't receive (US and allies) any condemn is because the Kissinger's [doctrine](https://www.academia.edu/12336723/_The_Kissinger_Doctrine_The_Triumph_of_Power_Politics_over_Justice_and_Humanity_):

**Politics always triumphs over justice.**

Comment: Law  is not the same thing as justice.

Comment: Resolutions are not laws, and the UN is not some kind of world government.  Every member nation retains its sovereignty.

Comment: @Andy international treaties such as UN charter are part of the legal system of the member nations (in Russia for instance, international treaties have precedence over federal laws except the constitution, in the US AFAIK the treaties have the same weight as federal laws).

Comment: @Anixx UN resolutions are not international treaties, so I fail to see your point.  And I seriously doubt the UN charter was wholesale imported into federal law.  But please, if that's not the case, I'd love a link that states that's the case.

Comment: @Andy the UN charter is a treaty that requires the parties to abide the UN Security Council resolutions. The General Assembly decisions are not binding though.

Comment: @Andy international treaties are not needed to be imported into the law. They are the law when they are ratified and signed. In Russian constitution, Article 15, part 4: "If international treaty sets up different provisions than the federal law, then the provisions of the international treaty apply". The same in constitution of Belarus and many other countries.

Comment: @Anixx And there are no resolutions from the SC on Syria.  There's a process in the US for treaties, and in the US government's eyes treaties aren't valid unless ratified by the Senate.  And I'd think a civil war can be considered a breach of the peace, allowing a member state to act.  Clearly at the end of the day, the UN is OK with what is going on in Syria including the US' and Russia's involvement, or they'd impose some kind of sanction.

Comment: @Andy the UN charter itself forbids interventions and wars unless approved by UN SC. If there were no resolutions, the invasion is illegal per UN Charter (unless in self-defense). The UN Charter is retified. No sanction the UN can impose on a permanent SC member. But this does not make its actions legal the does not make starting a war not a crime against humanity. Perfectly, the national law enfiorcement should take action and imprison those who started such war.

Comment: @Andy Russian Criminal Code, article 353, for instance: Planning, preparing and unleashing a war of aggression, up to 20 years in prison.

Comment: @Andy "And I'd think a civil war can be considered a breach of the peace, allowing a member state to act." - breach of peace does not allow any state to act, only those attacked, in self-defense. If the US was attacked by ISIS, they can act against it, but not against Syrian government. In Iraq the war was totally illegal.

Comment: @Anixx The UN charter is irrelevant, because as I've said every nation retains it sovereignty.  In the US, the Constitution trumps all, and the President (according to the SC) has the authority to deploy troops (which is separate from declaring war).  If no nation is sovereign over the US, the only laws it can break are its own.  Given that the President and Congress authorized military action in Syria, the US is not breaking its own laws.

Comment: @Anixx I have no idea why you keep quoting RUSSIAN law when we're talking about the US.  Russian law is meaningless to the US.  As far as acting against ISIS, that's exactly what the US is doing in Syria, fighting ISIS.  ISIS isn't a nation, its a terror group operating within existing nations.  One of the reasons to invade Iraq was the same; that Saddam was allowing Al-Qaeda to operate within its borders, and so the US went in to stop it (in addition to Afghanistan).

Comment: @Andy The ratified international treaties ARE laws in the US. And the UN charter is a ratified international treaty.

Comment: @Anixx And I've already explained why I think the actions were legal (namely, going after terror groups; i.e., self defense).

Comment: The unjust thing about Cuba is that they have to live under brutal left winged regime. Castro for 50 years denied the citizens the right to leave the country and Junkers called him a patriot who loved his people. If Raul Castro wants embargo to be lifted, he should give the power back to the people.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with international law is, that the leader of a country have to ratify and validate it. No country is or will be forced to ratify a treaty. But if a country didn't sign a treaty it is not bound to it; it's more or less voluntary. And even if a country has signed a treaty, it is no assurance that the country (or every future leadership) will uphold it's commitments.

Of course other countries can inflict sanctions or resolutions against a country that has broken international law. But since the UN is a democratic institution, there are ways to inhibit intended punishments (via veto for example). Additionally every country is free to terminate a treaty or deny the signing. 
In my (subjective) opinion, a lot of countries take international law more as a recommendation than binding law.

Comment: UN is **Not** a democratic institution

Comment: Sorry I expressed myself wrong. It's an institution that upholds and defend democratic principles. But I think it is working on democratic principles too (decisions are discussed, each member of the security council has a vote and it has veto powers to block decisions). Also it's charter starts with "We the people" if I recall correctly.

Comment: member of the security council dont elected democratically. 5 of them (which has veto power) are permanent. these are permanent members *By force*.

Comment: @BobbyPi When has UN ever upheld democratic principles? A resolution can be passed by vast majority in General Assembly, It still won't matter if a permanent SC member vetoes it. That is clear violation of democratic principles. Veto right of unelected permanent members is not democratic at all

Comment: Do the UN not uphold democracy and try to spread it globally? I always thought the UN is fighting for more democracy in the world; am I wrong?

Comment: Bobby, that's the US foreign policy lol

Comment: I'm wrong. I confused or mixed protection of human rights and protection of democracy. I thought the UN is fighting for both. In hindsight it's illogical (since many if not most member states are no democracies).

Comment: @BobbyPi China is one of the major players in the UN.  They're a totalitarian dictatorship that subjugates their population.  The purpose of the UN is an established international channel for diplomacy, arbitration, and governance.

Comment: @BobbyPi The purpose of the UN is to try and get countries to talk things out instead of going to war, and if that fails hopefully get enough other members to force a misbehaving country to knock it off.

Comment: First the US ratified the UN charter making a treaty. Second, by the constitution, a treaty signed by the US gov't has the force of law. Third there's "State of Missouri v. Holland" which is too complicated for a comment (but do read it). All this to say that if a war is illegal by the UN charter it is, while the US is still a signatory, illegal according to US law.

Comment: @user1512321: That "force of law" is still subservient to the Constitution.  The powers exercised by POTUS and Congress are granted by the Constitution, so just as no federal law can revoke them, neither can any treaty.

Comment: @BenVoigt Except that State of Missouri v. Holland revoked constitutional powers granted to States in favor of a treaty. If you don't like a treaty, rip it up. But don't sully the integrity of the US' Word by not honoring commitments.